# Forcing error in Database.convertLead() for test coverage

Tags: apex, unit-test

Does anyone know of a situation in which the *Database.convertLead()* method  fails by returning errors in the *LeadConvertResult* object that it returns, rather than throwing an exception?  I'm trying to handle that situation like this:

```
Database.LeadConvertResult lcr = Database.convertLead(lc);
if (!lcr.IsSuccess()) {
    errormsg = lcr.errors.get(0).message;
    return null;
}
```

but all of the approaches I've tried in my test cases to force an error on *convertLead* result in an exception being thrown instead of returning an object where *IsSuccess()* returns false.

Maybe I shouldn't worry so much about being at 98% test coverage rather than 100%, but it's bugging me, and I'm wondering if the proper approach to handling these errors is try/catch rather than checking the result. Can anyone offer some suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's two versions of most Database methods. The first version accepts a single parameter, either a single value or a list, and the second version accepts an additional Boolean value called `allOrNone`. In the single-parameter version, `allOrNone` is assumed to be **true**, so normally you'd only call the two-parameter version if you wanted to set the value to **false**.

When `allOrNone` is set to **true**, *any* error causes a `DMLException` to be thrown. When `allOrNone` is set to **false**, however, you can then receive errors normally in the `LeadConvertResult` return value. Since you're using the single parameter version of `convertLead`, `isSuccess` will always be **true** if your code reaches that point in execution, because otherwise an exception would have been thrown.

When you pass a single value rather than a list, the `allOrNone` parameter serves to control how errors are indicated. **True** means a `DMLException` will always be thrown when an error occurs, while **false** means errors are returned normally in the `getErrors` call from the `LeadConvertResult` return value. However, even with `allOrNone` set to **false**, an exception can still bubble up to your code, for example, if you have a trigger which causes a `NullPointerException`.

In the code you've written, I would call the conditional statement an impossible condition; it will never, ever execute because the only legal value when `allOrNone` is **true** is that `isSuccess` will also be **true**.

Comment: Ah,  so rather than try to force an error to get my coverage, I can just remove the code that can never be executed. That works for me! Thanks!